# Embedding Images into SVG file like Inkscape extensions using Python

Tags: python, svg, gtk3, inkscape, nft

I wonder is there any Python library I can use to create an SVG file, insert JPG/PNG into it, and then use `Extension` > `Images` > `Embed Images` like functions to embed image files into the SVG file instead of linking it.

I'm trying to build an NFT random generator project using Python and GTK3. It will take the SVG file as the input, modify the layers or tag style, and then render out the SVG as a PNG file using GTK3. So far I have creat the SVG file using Inkscape by importing the images and embedding them manually using those extensions below.

[image: screenshoots]

Answer (score 3):

There are python SVG libraries like svgwrite and drawSvg.  You can find them by google searching "SVG python library".  But the problem you described probably can be easily solved without a library.

The SVG file is essentially an XML file.  An SVG file with an embedded image look like this (you can open an SVG file with a text editor).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing-image.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.1.1 (1:1.1+202109281954+c3084ef5ed)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.64052329"
     inkscape:cx="396.55076"
     inkscape:cy="561.25984"
     inkscape:window-width="1551"
     inkscape:window-height="970"
     inkscape:window-x="26"
     inkscape:window-y="23"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <image
       width="108.661"
       height="81.49575"
       preserveAspectRatio="none"
       xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QAqRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAABADEBAgAHAAAAGgAAAAAAAABH
b29nbGUAAP/iAmRJQ0NfUFJPRklMRQABAQAAAlQAAAAABAAAAG1udHJSR0IgWFlaIAfgAAwACAAJ
//////
lots of lines removed //////
//////
G/JRmDkZRlKnckbJHaDV/UXciooHjLVBUz//2Q==
"
       id="image97"
       x="32.482494"
       y="23.698683" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can create such a file in a python program and put your image file data there.  If you want to see what the "Embed Images..." extension does, you can find the python file at this location (assuming you are on Linux). You can search "image_embed.py" file if you are under Windows.

```
/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/image_embed.py
```

The code is actually very simple. It reads the image file and sets it as an attribute of the image node.  You can do the same thing in your Python program.

Comment: @EkkyArmandi if that did answer your question, you might consider check-marking it (and upvoting).